# pandas df filter on rows with any n rows satisfying condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df with many columns and I want to select all rows that have any 2 column-values nonzero. filtering on rows where specific columns are nonzero is trivial, I mean this is probably trivial as well but it's eluding me. `have`/`want` dataframes for reproduceable example below:

```
import pandas as pd

have = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'grp1': [1,0,0,0,0],
        'grp2': [0,2,0,0,0],
        'grp3': [1,1,0,0,5]})

want = have.iloc[0:2]
```

```
>>> want
   ID  grp1  grp2  grp3
0   1     1     0     1
1   2     0     2     1
```

last note - I pass back and forth between pandas and sql(ite) a lot, so if there's a more elegant way to do this in sql than pandas that I'm missing, I'm open to that too.

Comment: What about ID5? there is non-zero value in group3. Why did you leave it out

Comment: hey sorry I was unclear, edited to clarify the question. I'm looking for rows where any 2 columns are nonzero. so row 1 & 2 have two different nonzero columns, row 5 has only one.

Comment: In total how many columns do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pandas:

```
have[have.iloc[:,1:].gt(0).sum(1).gt(1)]
 
   ID  grp1  grp2  grp3
0   1     1     0     1
1   2     0     2     1
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need:

`have.loc[(have.iloc[:,1:]!=0).sum(1)>1]` as you said non-zero values.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the column type to bool then zero will be `Fasle` and non zero will be `True` and sum the `True` to get non zero count.

```py
out = have[have.filter(like='grp').astype(bool).sum(axis=1).ge(2)]
```

```
print(out)

   ID  grp1  grp2  grp3
0   1     1     0     1
1   2     0     2     1
```